# how can I make step two so the output will be: "defabc123ghi"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I make step two so that output will be: `defabc123ghi`?

1. More than one word? Reverse each word and combine first with second, third with fourth and so on ... (odd number of words => last
   one stays alone, but has to be reversed too)
2. Start it again until there's only one word without spaces
3. Return your result

```js
function reverse_and_combine_text(str) {
  var result = []
  var combined = []
  var reversed = []
  var arr = str.split(" ");
  for (var n = 0; n < arr.length / 2; n++) {}
  arr.forEach(el => {
    reversed.push(el.split('').reverse().join(''))
  })

  reversed.forEach((el, i) => {
    combined.push(el.concat(reversed[i + 1]))
  })
  combined.filter((el, i) => {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      result.push(el)
    }
  })

  return result
}

console.log(reverse_and_combine_text("abc def ghi 123"));
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `for` loop with no body?

Comment: that was an oversight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the logic until you have only one word left. 
I would also avoid joining a character array back to a string for as long you have not reached that point, because you will only have to split that string again into individual characters when you still have more than one word left over. So you might as well stick with arrays until you are at the end.

Here is how you could achieve it with a loop that verifies whether you have only one word left:

```js
function reverse_and_combine_text(str) {
    // immediately convert words to subarrays of characters (using spread syntax)
    let words = str.split(" ").map(word => [...word]);
    // This loop ensures you continue the process until you have one word left
    while (words.length > 1) {
        words = words.map(word => 
            word.reverse()
        ).reduce((acc, word, i, words) => // pair words
           i % 2 == 0 ? acc.concat([word.concat(words[i + 1] || [])]) : acc,
        []);
    }
    return words[0].join(""); // Only at the end, turn the subarray back to string
}

console.log(reverse_and_combine_text("abc def ghi 123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `result` array has more than one element, join the elements into a string and call the function recursively.

Also, your `filter()` call should be `forEach()`. Use `filter()` when the function checks a condition and you want to return an array of the elements that satisfy that condition.

You're also not combining pairs of words correctly. Your method only works when there are an even number of words. When it's odd, you concatenate `undefined` to the last word. You need to skip concatenating the next word when you get to the last word.

```js
function reverse_and_combine_text(str) {
  var result = []
  var combined = []
  var reversed = []
  var arr = str.split(" ");
  for (var n = 0; n < arr.length / 2; n++) {}
  arr.forEach(el => {
    reversed.push(el.split('').reverse().join(''))
  })
  
  reversed.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (i < reversed.length - 1) {
      combined.push(el.concat(reversed[i + 1]));
    } else {
      combined.push(el);
    }
  })
  combined.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      result.push(el)
    }
  })

  if (result.length == 1) {
    return result[0];
  } else {
    return reverse_and_combine_text(result.join(" "));
  }
}

console.log(reverse_and_combine_text("abc def ghi 123"));
console.log(reverse_and_combine_text("sdfsdf wee sdffg 342234 ftt"));
```

Comment: can you please explain this ** return reverse_and_combine_text(result.join(" "));**

Comment: That's the recursive call that I described in my answer.

Comment: `join()` is the opposite of `split()`. So if you have an array like `["abc", "def"]` it creates the string `"abc def"`

Comment: Then we call the function again, which is what step 2 says.

Comment: i tried this input "sdfsdf wee sdffg 342234 ftt" and the output should be  "gffds432243fdsfdseewttf" but instead i got this output "gffds432243fdsfdseewdenifednuttfundefined"!!

Comment: `undefined` is because you concatenate the element after the end of the array in the `reversed.forEach()` loop. I've added a check for that.